# VBA calculate sum from active cell to its above cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I am VBA Noob and seeking for help, my ActiveCell is currently in cell A8 and I want to get the sum of cell A7 to A1 with the use of loop then the value will appear in cell A8. Also, same with if I change my ActiveCell to C8 and I will still get same procedure.

Record macro gave me this one

```
Range("A1:A7,A8").Select
Range("A8").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-7]C:R[-1]C)"
```

I want to change it to loop so that the value of A1:A7 will appear on my ActiveCell A8

Comment: Why not a formula? If you still want a VBA solution, try recording a macro and tinker with it.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To place the **value** in the activecell, **using a loop** try:

```
Sub SumAboveLoop()
    Dim r As Range, rAbove As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Set r = ActiveCell
    Set rAbove = Range(r.Offset(-1, 0), Cells(1, r.Column))
    v = 0
    For Each rr In rAbove
        v = v + rr.Value
    Next rr
    r.Value = v
End Sub
```

To place a **value** in the activecell **without a loop**, try:

```
Sub SumAboveV()
    Dim r As Range, rAbove As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set r = ActiveCell
    Set rAbove = Range(r.Offset(-1, 0), Cells(1, r.Column))
    r.Value = wf.Sum(rAbove)
End Sub
```

To place a **formula** in the activecell **without a loop**, try:

```
Sub SumAboveF()
    Dim r As Range, rAbove As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set r = ActiveCell
    Set rAbove = Range(r.Offset(-1, 0), Cells(1, r.Column))
    r.Formula = "=SUM(" & rAbove.Address & ")"
End Sub
```